# How to re-execute failed jobs in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

When executing a batch of circuits using the [IBMQJobManager](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.IBMQJobManager.html) and attempting to combine all the results of all jobs with [`combine_results`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.ManagedResults.combine_results.html#qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.ManagedResults.combine_results) I get the [IBMQManagedResultDataNotAvailable](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.IBMQManagedResultDataNotAvailable.html#qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.IBMQManagedResultDataNotAvailable) exception as some of the jobs in the set have failed. Is it possible to re-execute only the failed jobs and then combine all the results?

```
job_set = IBMQJobManager().run(batch_of_circuits, backend=ibmq_foo)
job_set_results = job_set.results() 
job_set_counts = job_set_results.combine_results() # exception thrown on this line
```

Answer (score 0):

`IBMQJobManager` finds the jobs in a set by their tags and names. So yes, if you re-submit the same job with the same tags/job name, it'll be picked up by the job manager. Something like

```
failed_job = backend.retrieve_job(FAILED_JOB_ID)
qobj = failed_job.qobj()
backend.run(qobj, job_name=failed_job.name(), job_tags=failed_job.tags())
jm = IBMQJobManager()
job_set = jm.retrieve_job_set(JOB_SET_ID, provider)
```

There's also [an issue](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider/issues/636) open on automatically retrying job submit if it fails.